# There are infinite number of degree $1$ principal prime ideal in a ring of algebraic integers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field. I was wondering how we know that there are infinite number of degree $1$ principal prime ideal of $K$.

Context: This is related to an example of polynomial representing infinitely many primes. Let $K$ be of degree $n$ and $\beta_1, ..., \beta_n$ be a $\mathbb{Z}$-basis of the ring of integers. Then the fact that
$$
N_{K/\mathbb{Q}} ( \beta_1 X_1 + ... +\beta_n X_n ) \in \mathbb{Z}[X_1, ..., X_N]
$$
represents infinite number of primes follows from the above fact. 
Thank you very much!

Comment: It follows from the existence of a  pole at s=1 of the Dedekind zeta function.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Could you possibly elaborate on it by any chance? Thanks!

Comment: This is usually proved in the classical approach to class field theory; see e.g. the recent book by Nancy Childress or, if you dare, Algebraic Numbers by Serge Lang.